# How to optimize pulling multiple results of text comparison across multiple tabs in a Google Sheet? (QUERY vs FILTER vs other functions)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

new as heck here and I trying to find the best way to further optimize a set of sheets functions.

The starting function was essentially 26 stacked filter functions being used to reference individual cells beneath containing names(strings), find the IDs associated with the names in these cells, pull the IDs from the "ref" sheet, and create a url that contains these IDs. The function, stripped of confidential data:

`=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://url.com/stuff?ids=",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B3))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B3)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B4))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B4)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B5))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B5)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B6))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B6)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B7))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B7)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B8))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B8)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B9))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B9)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B10))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B10)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B11))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B11)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B12))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B12)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B13))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B13)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B14))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B14)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B15))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B15)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B16))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B16)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B17))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B17)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B18))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B18)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B19))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B19)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B20))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B20)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B21))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B21)),",",if(isna(filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B22))=true,"",filter(ref!$B:$B,ref!$A:$A=B22)),"&morestuff=true"),"Group A")`

The best I could do to optimize this was to compile the IDs in one cell (B1) with this QUERY function within a TEXTJOIN:

`=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE, QUERY(ref!$A$2:$B, "select B where A = '"&B3&"' or A = '"&B4&"' or A = '"&B5&"' or A = '"&B6&"' or A = '"&B7&"' or A = '"&B8&"' or A = '"&B9&"' or A = '"&B10&"' or A = '"&B11&"' or A = '"&B12&"' or A = '"&B13&"' or A = '"&B14&"' or A = '"&B15&"' or A = '"&B16&"' or A = '"&B17&"' or A = '"&B18&"' or A = '"&B19&"' or A = '"&B20&"' or A = '"&B21&"' or A = '"&B22&"' or A = '"&B23&"' or A = '"&B24&"' or A = '"&B25&"' or A = '"&B26&"' or A = '"&B27&"' or A = '"&B28&"' or A = '"&B29&"' "))`

Then do the url generation in another cell (B2), referencing B1 for the IDs:

`=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://url.com/stuff?ids=", ",", B1, "&morestuff=true"), "Group A")`

I then copied these across Groups B-Z

I tried multiple variations of FILTER stacked in ARRAYFORMULA but I couldn't get it to work. I'm unsure if there is a syntax I should be using to better handle matching text that I am not quite figuring out. Simply matching by first letter is not an option as there are names that do not qualify for the groupings contained within the "ref" sheet for use in other data sets.

So my question here is really: is there an easier way to compile this where I don't have to reference each cell individually for matches on the "ref" sheet?

For an example of the sheet I am working with, this link should work:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ykSldWyQnPcar9G21ljLOzm3dWC1i82kMaQJuSKHajc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with some example of desired output

Comment: It's about time you used the name range feature, unless you like to suffer.

Comment: Edited the OP but also here is the link to an example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ykSldWyQnPcar9G21ljLOzm3dWC1i82kMaQJuSKHajc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use another `textjoin` to construct your query string as follows:

```
="select B"&if(counta(B3:B)=0,""," where A='")&textjoin("' or A='",true,B3:B)
```

Not only is this much shorter than manually typing each cell but it will also expand infinitely downward as required.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up having to modify it a smidgen to get it to play right with the sheet. I ended up going with:


`=IFNA(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE, QUERY(ref!$A$2:$B, "select B where A = '"&textjoin("' or A = '",true,B3:B)&"'")), "")`

Thank you so much for setting me on the right path!